# Writing better code for session variable check from render_to_response

Tags: django, session

Is this the most efficient and clean way to check the sessions for a username variable and output (depending on whether or not it is there) either "You are logged in." or "You are logged out."?

**PYTHON (DJANGO)**

```
def logged_in(request)
    return render_to_response('loggedincheck.html', {'request': request.session.get['username']})
```

**HTML**

> {% if request %}
>       You're logged in. {% else %}
>       You're not logged in. {% endif %}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django comes with some template context processors - which are simply functions that insert variables into every template that is rendered on your site.

As @Jack states, one of these is called `django.core.context_processors.auth`. This inserts a variable called `user` into every template, and is enabled by default.

Therefore, to find out if a user is logged in or not, you should use this code in your templates:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    You're logged in.
{% else %}
    You're not logged in.
{% endif %}
```

The problem with using the code that Jack gave, is that the `user` variable *always* exists - so that will always evaluate to `True` (so long as you are using the `django.core.context_processors.request` context processor, which is *not* enabled by default). Therefore, to find out if the user is actually logged in, you must use the `is_authenticated()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`django.contrib.auth`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) and both [`django.core.context_processors.auth`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates) and [`django.core.context_processors.request`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) are in your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1), you can simply use:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    You're logged in.
{% else %}
    You're not logged in.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: -1 `request.user` is always present, as an unauthenticated user (every user) is a user too.

Comment: You're correct.  I am used to checking specific permissions instead of if they're authenticated, so I forgot to chuck that bit in there.  I fixed it up.